# How should I solve this combinations scenario with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, combinations, lodash

For a tournament with a minimum of 8 teams and a max of 18, I gotta determinate the matches calendar. Tournament got 17 round or match days. So every team must encounter another team each match day. If there's less than 18 teams encounters can repeat so a team can play against another more than once.

[This is an example for 18 teams tournament.](http://pastebin.com/FwXTZjZp) [And this would be a case for less than 18 teams fixture, here in particular 9 teams](http://pastebin.com/NB1JX9h4).

So, I gotta do permutations and then arrange them on distinct rounds. I've tried:

**Combinations:**

```
function k_combinations(set, k) {
    var i, j, combs, head, tailcombs;

    if (k > set.length || k <= 0) {
        return [];
    }

    if (k == set.length) {
        return [set];
    }

    if (k == 1) {
        combs = [];
        for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            combs.push([set[i]]);
        }
        return combs;
    }

    combs = [];
    for (i = 0; i < set.length - k + 1; i++) {
        head = set.slice(i, i+1);
        tailcombs = k_combinations(set.slice(i + 1), k - 1);
        for (j = 0; j < tailcombs.length; j++) {
            combs.push(head.concat(tailcombs[j]));
        }
    }
    return combs;
}

var teams = [   {name: 'Real Madrid'},
                {name: 'Las Palmas'},
                {name: 'Alavés'},
                {name: 'Valencia'},
                {name: 'Sevilla'},
                {name: 'Betis'},
                {name: 'Córdoba'},
                {name: 'Deportivo'},
                {name: 'Atlético de Madrid'},
                {name: 'Levante'},
                {name: 'Rayo Vallecano'},
                {name: 'Athletic Bilbao'},
                {name: 'Osasuna'},
                {name: 'Zaragoza'},
                {name: 'Villareal'},
                {name: 'Racing de Santander'},
                {name: 'Espanyol'},
                {name: 'Cádiz'},
                ];
// Compute whole encounters combinations.
var seasonMatches = k_combinations(teams,2);
```

**Rounds arrangement of combinations:**

```
var calendar = {};
for (var i = 0; i<17; i++) {
    calendar[i+1] = [];
}
var encounters = seasonMatches;

for (var i = 0; i<Object.keys(calendar).length; i++) {

    encounters.map(function (match,index) {

        if (! _.any(calendar, function (m) {

           return m[0].name === match[0].name || m[1].name === match[1].name || m[0].name === match[1].name || m[1].name === match[0].name;
        })) {
            calendar[i+1].push(match);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using lodash to simplify the existance checking of any encounter in a previous round.

The problem I've got is that this way I got SAME encounters for every round in calendar. And, if I add a splice to seasonMatches, I endup with distinct matches per round.

[I've got a fiddle with this example shown above.](https://jsfiddle.net/bkrdn9qf/)
How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you like to work hard :) there is a much simpler way ([jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/guloqum/edit?js,console)):

```
var teamsCount = 9;
var matchDays = 17;
var matches = [];
var teams = _.shuffle(_.range(teamsCount));
while(matches.length < matchDays){
  var newMatches = _(teams).chunk(2).partition(function(match){
    return match.length === 2;
  }).value();
  matches = matches.concat(newMatches[0]);
  if(newMatches[1].length) { // one team was left out, let's make sure it is playing
    // we put it first, and add the other teams, shuffled, without that one team
    teams = newMatches[1][0].concat(_.shuffle(_.without(_.range(teamsCount), newMatches[1][0][0])));
  } else {
    teams = _.shuffle(_.range(teamsCount));
  }
}

// we might get more then we need
matches = _.take(matches, matchDays);

_.each(matches, function(match, index){
  console.log('round ' + index + ': ' + match);
});
```

Explanation:
Since you imposed no other limitations (for example, each team has to play each other), it is enough to take the team, shuffle them and chunk them 2 at a time (= a match). We then partition the chunks to real matches (2 teams array) and left overs (1 team array).

We take the real matches and add them to the existing ones. If we have left overs, we keep it, and concat to it the shuffled teams (without the left over team) and chunk it again. We continue until we have enough matches. Since we might get more matches then we need, we take only the first 17 ones.

The JSbin is more elaborate and converts the matches to team names as well.

I tried to look at your code to see why you get the pattern you showed but it is too complicated for me to understand, I like to do things the easy way ;-)